# SCM URL relative to parent SCM URL in POMs

Tags: version-control, maven-2, maven

I have a Maven project made of several modules and sub-modules.
I use SVN to version the source files.

### The short story

How do I specify URL in scm properties of a POM file, that are relative to the ones of its parent.

### The long story

Some modules and their sub modules share a common version number / release process, and some use independant ones. For the module with independant version number, I have set up a branches/trunk/tags layout, for the release-plugin to be happy.

For that, I haveb two SVN layouts in my repository. One holds all the trunk/branches/tags mess, the other one holds a clean ready-to-checkout working directory with svn:external references to the trunks.

This looks like this; You have the real world SVN layout, with trunk/branches/tags mess:

> - *pom.xml* (main parent)
> - **utils**
>
>   - branches
>   - tags
>   - trunk
>
>     - *pom.xml*, src, target, etc...
> - **data-model** (*released*)
>
>   - branches
>   - tags
>   - trunk
>
>     - *pom.xml*
>     - **lib**
>
>       - *pom.xml*, src, target, etc...
>     - **server**
>
>       - *pom.xml*, src, target, etc...
>     - **client**
>
>       - *pom.xml*, src, target, etc...
> - **bin-modules**
>
>   - **bin-module-1** (*released*)
>
>     - branches
>     - tags
>     - trunk
>
>       - *pom.xml*, src, target, etc ...
>   - **bin-module-2** (*released*)
>
>     - branches
>     - tags
>     - trunk
>
>       - *pom.xml*, src, target, etc...

And the clean layout of the working direcotry, hidding the branches/trunk stuff with "svn:externals" tags:

> - *pom.xml* (main parent)
> - **utils** (-> *utils/trunk*)
>
>   - *pom.xml*, src, target, etc...
> - **data-model** (-> *data-model/trunk*)
>
>   - *pom.xml*
>
>     - **lib**
>
>       - *pom.xml*, src, target, etc...
>     - **server**
>
>       - *pom.xml*, src, target, etc...
>     - **client**
>
>       - *pom.xml*, src, target, etc...
> - **bin-modules**
>
>   - *pom.xml*
>   - **bin-module-1** (-> *bin-module-1/trunk*)
>
>     - *pom.xml*, src, target, etc ...
>   - **bin-module-2** (-> *bin-module-2/trunk*)
>
>     - *pom.xml*, src, target, etc...

So far, so good.
I have set up the root SCM URLs in my parent POM, and Maven correctly implies the URLs for the sub-modules.
I have checked it with `mvn help:effective-pom`

I have the following scm urls:

- **root** : [root-url]
- **utils** : [root-url]/utils
- **data-model** : [root-url]/data-model/
- **data-model/lib** : [root-url]/data-model/lib
- **data-model/client** : [root-url]/data-model/client
- **data-model/server** : [root-url]/data-model/server
- **bin-module-1** : [root-url]/bin-module-1/
- **bin-module-2** : [root-url]/bin-module-2/

But Maven is unaware of the actual SVN layout.
I would like it to see  :

- **root** : [root-url]
- **utils** : [root-url]/utils/trunk
- **data-model** : [root-url]/data-model/trunk
- **data-model/lib** : [root-url]/data-model/trunk/lib
- **data-model/client** : [root-url]/data-model/trunk/client
- **data-model/server** : [root-url]/data-model/trunk/server
- **bin-module-1** : [root-url]/bin-module-1/trunk
- **bin-module-2** : [root-url]/bin-module-2/trunk

For that, I need to add a *scm* section to the `pom.xml` of *data-model*, *bin-module-1* and *bin-module-2*.

I have tried something like (for data-model) :

```
<scm>
    <connection>./data-model/trunk</connection>
    <developerConnection>./sdr/trunk</developerConnection>
    <url>./sdr/trunk</url
</scm>
```

Or

```
<scm>
    <connection>${project.parent.scm.connection}/data-model/trunk</connection>
    <developerConnection>${project.parent.scm.developerConnection}/data-model/trunk</developerConnection>
    <url>${project.parent.scm.url}/data-model/trunk</url>
</scm>
```

But none seem to work. The properties ${...} are not even replaced.
So, how do I override a SCM path, relative to its parent SCM URL ?

Any help, advice, would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Raphael

Answer (score 5):

I would have thought that this works:

```
<scm>
    <connection>${project.parent.scm.connection}/data-model/trunk</connection>
    <developerConnection>${project.parent.scm.developerConnection}/data-model/trunk</developerConnection>
    <url>${project.parent.scm.url}/data-model/trunk</url>
</scm>
```

If it doesn't, there's still the possibility to assign these values programmatically (I'll use [GMaven](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Home) to do that, but you can also use the antrun plugin or write a custom plugin)

First, set a property

```
<properties>
    <relativeScmPath>data-model/trunk</relativeScmPath>
</properties>
```

Then assign a relative offset to all SCM properties:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>assign-scm</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>
                <![CDATA[
                def parentScm = project.parent.scm;
                def thisScm = project.scm;
                def relPath = project.properties['relativeScmPath'];
                ['connection','developerConnection','url'].each{
                    thisScm[it] = parentScm[it] + relPath;
                }
                ]]>
                </source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

You could add this to the root pom and change it so that it runs only if it finds the property, and then you can automatically set the value for n sub modules by simply adding the property to them.

Comment: beware, that using variables in the scm url might trigger an old bug in the maven-release-plugin.