# Duplicate artifactId in child pom

Tags: maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I want a parent pom to define some properties for numerous child poms to inherit. However when I try and use the artifactId within one of these properties in the parent pom, it duplicates in the child's effective pom. Very basic example below. Assume I have all the valid fields needed for poms (groupId, version, packaging etc).

The parent pom's effective pom has a scm connection value of `www.mysite.com/parent-pom`. But the child's effective pom has a scm connection value of `www.mysite.com/child-pom/child-pom`. How do I gain this inheritance of the property and general structure of the connection url, without the duplicate artifactId. I want the child pom to have a scm connection of `www.mysite.com/child-pom`.

Parent:

```
<project>
  <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
  <properties>
    <scmurl>www.mysite.com</scmurl>
  </properties>
  <scm>
    <connection>${scmurl}/${artifactId}</connection>
  </scm>
</project>
```

Child:

```
<project>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>child-pom</artifactId>
</project>
```

Comment: The scm connections is one of the things which do not make sense to define properties for, cause at the first time you will do a release the properties will be replaced by the values and afterwards you have the literal values there which does not help in the end. Furthermore Are we talking about a multi module build? If yes than only the parent should have an scm element not the childs.

Comment: Not talking about multi-module. I'm talking about separate projects. One parent which defines versions for common dependencies, and then any number of other projects would inherit this. One thing I wanted to define was the SCM url.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142998/maven-scm-url-relative-to-the-parent) and especially [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875833/scm-url-relative-to-parent-scm-url-in-poms)?

Comment: Try changing `${artifactId}` to `${project.artifactId}`. Does it help?

Comment: For independent project is does not make sense as well. So defining properties in your pom which inherits from a company pom only works for the first time you create the new project after the first release all those properties will be replaced by their values.

Comment: @eis If I understand the OP correctly it's not about _relative to parent_ but _relative to current project._

Comment: @EldadAK I tried `${artifactId}` ⇒ `${project.artifactId}.` It does not help.

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't follow you. You're saying that after the first release the properties will be replaced by their values. However my child project is dependent on a released version of the parent-pom, and the child pom's scm connection doesn't have any reference to the value in the parent pom. As you can see above it picks up the scmurl property fine and then puts in the child pom's artifactId (twice...). It doesn't use the released parent pom literal artifactId at all.

Comment: @khmarbaise why? who replaces the properties with values? if i use mvn-release-plugin it does not suppose to replace properties (it does not use mvn-versions-plugin...)

Comment: Definitely a keming issue on the title of this post...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

edwardmlyte,

There are 2 solutions to what you're trying to do, but neither of them are optimal.

**Fundamental Problem**

If Maven SCM plugin detects that `<scm>` block has been defined in your parent but *NOT* in your child, then it will reason that your child's SCM path is simply the subdir of the parent. In your case there's an additional wrinkle that your parent's url itself contains `${project.artifactId}` which gets interpolated at the child level prior to tacking on the artifactId again.

Basically, it's doing the following:

```
project.scm.connection=${parent.scm.connection}/${project.artifactId}
project.scm.connection=${scmurl}/${project.artifactId}/${project.artifactId}
project.scm.connection=www.mysite.com/child-pom/child-pom
```

The fact that your parent's url contains `${artifactId}` compounds the confusion, but even if you hardcode the url to `www.mysite.com/parent-pom/` you won't be able to get around the fact that SCM plugin thinks `child-pom` is a subdir of the parent's url and so will simply tack it onto the end of the path.

Your 2 options are:

**Redundant but Simple**

Put the following into every child's pom.xml file:

```
<scm>
    <connection>${scmurl}/${artifactId}</connection>
</scm>
```

It's annoying but relatively straightforward.

**Efficient but Dodgy**

Have parent-pom contain the following:

```
<scm>
    <connection>${scmurl}/</connection>
</scm>
```

That will result in each child will have correct url, but the parent itself will be messed up.

You can get around that problem by putting the parent's correct url into a profile:

```
<profile>
    <id>parent-profile</id>
    <scm>
        <connection>${scmurl}/parent-pom</connection>
    </scm>
</profile>


$ mvn -Pparent-profile ...
```

It's less obvious and prone to manual error, but it'll avoid the need to edit each child's pom file.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not all that dissimilar to @333kenshin and was in fact derived from it, but I think that it results in a slightly terser paste.

In my parent pom I have added the following to `<properties>`

```
<git.account>xenworks</git.account>
<git.base>bitbucket.org/${git.account}/${project.artifactId}</git.base>
<git.conn>scm:git:https://${git.base}.git</git.conn>
<git.devConn>scm:git:ssh://git@${git.base}.git</git.devConn>
<git.url>https://${git.base}</git.url>
```

Now in the children and parent I can define scm as follows.

```
<scm>
  <connection>${git.conn}</connection>
  <developerConnection>${git.devConn}</developerConnection>
  <url>${git.url}</url>
  <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

the final contribution I'd like to make is there is an [open bug on this in the Maven Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MPIR-234)

Answer (score 0):

Where does `${scmurl}` come from? The property is called `url.`

If one adapts `parent-pom` accordingly:

```
 <scmurl>www.mysite.com</scmurl>
```

... the behavior is as described in the OQ:

```
/parent-pom$ mvn help:effective-pom
  ...
  <scm>
    <connection>www.mysite.com/parent-pom</connection>
  </scm>
  ...
```

`<relativePath>../parent-pom</relativePath>` (assuming they are siblings in the file system) has to be added to `child-pom` if `parent-pom` has not been `install`ed into the local Maven repo (yet). Otherwise the following will fail:

```
/child-pom$ mvn help:effective-pom
  ...
  <scm>
    <connection>www.mysite.com/child-pom/child-pom</connection>
  </scm>
  ...
```

This looks strange to me at first sight, too. I'm still scouring the docs to find a (logical) explanation for this.

Replacing `${artifactId}` with `${project.artifactId}` – as suggested in the comments – does not help.

Repeating `<scm><connection>${scmurl}/${artifactId}</connection></scm>` in `child-pom` helps:

```
/child-pom$ mvn help:effective-pom
  ...
  <scm>
    <connection>www.mysite.com/child-pom</connection>
  </scm>
  ...
```

However, I'd consider [khmarbaise's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) comments to the question.