# How to prevent artifactId from being appended to <SCM> connection URI?

Tags: java, maven, maven-scm

I am trying to define my `<SCM>` connection tag in a parent pom.  However, due to the provider I am using (Jazz) I do not wish my artifactId from being appended in the child artifact.

I found reference to an old thread indicating that appending a trailing / to the connection URI would prevent the artifactId from being appended, but this is not the case.

For example if the following is in my parent pom:

```
<scm>     
  <connection>scm:jazz:https://jazz.domain.com/ccm:MyProjectName</connection>
</scm>
```

My child's effective pom shows the connection as being:

```
<connection>scm:jazz:https://jazz.domain.com/ccm:MyProjectName/child-module-name</connection>
```

I would like to prevent `child-module-name` from being appended to the connection string.  I read on an old thread that appending a trailing / to the connection string in the parent would prevent the child's artifactId from being appended, but this does not seem to be the case.

I am using Maven 3.2.3.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503589/duplicate-artifactid-in-child-pom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem here. Apparently it's been an issue for years that the community can't decide how or whether to fix. So the workaround is to specify the scm setting in each child.

See:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3244

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-2290

Comment: Thanks - that's pretty much what I had come to figure as well.